Amazon Textract Python
I am using the async function GetDocumentAnalysis along with implementing pagination(next_token property of Amazon Textract). I am using an iterative approach for this and the loop runs once with a JobStatus of 'InProgress" and then I get Invalid Parameter exception from Textract Api
I am not sure what is wrong in my code.
Attached is the code
`def receive_analysis_data(job_id_value, next_token):
"""
    This method uses Textract async function GetDocumentAnalysis to extract
    the analyzed data from the document in JSON Key-value pair format and store it in a Python dictionary
    :param next_token: pagination value initialized to None and sent as argument
    :parameter job_id_value is the JobId received by Textract async function StartDocumentAnalysis
"""
token = " " # used for next_token value
job_status = {} # used for storing JobStatus
retry_attempts = 5
block_list = {} # used to store the JSON data returned by GetDocumentAnalysis
result = {} # used to store JSON data of response and next_response
while retry_attempts > 0: 
    if next_token is None:
        response = client.get_document_analysis(JobId=job_id_value)
        job_status = response['JobStatus']
        if job_status == "SUCCEEDED":
            result.update(response)
            token = result.get('NextToken')
        else:
            retry_attempts -= 1
            logger.info("job status is: %s ", job_status)
            logger.info("Retrying to analyze the document. retry attempts left %d:", retry_attempts)
            time.sleep(10)

    if token is not None:
        next_response = client.get_document_analysis(JobId=job_id_value, NextToken=token)
        job_status = next_response['JobStatus']
        if job_status == "SUCCEEDED":
            result.update(next_response)
            token = next_response.get('NextToken')
        else:
            retry_attempts -= 1
            logger.info("job status is: %s ", job_status)
            logger.info("Retrying to analyze the document. retry attempts left %d:", retry_attempts)
            time.sleep(10)
    else:
        logger.info("Analyzing document completed. JobStatus %s ", job_status)
        write_json_file(block_list)
        parse_json(block_list)
        break`

